# Can we use ? operator in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to use  this sql query?

```
select ([discount_type]='Percent') ? [Percent]+'%' : [Amount]+'RS' as [Discount] from [admin].[discount] where [discount_id]=2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a `CASE` (which is pretty much like a `switch` in many other languages)

```
SELECT
   CASE [discount_type]
   WHEN 'Percent' THEN [Percent] + '%'
   ELSE [Amount] + 'RS' END as [Discount]
FROM [admin].[discount]
WHERE [discount_id] = 2
```

Note that the rest of the query uses your code as is, i.e. assuming that `Percent` can be concatenated with a string without prior conversion.

Comment: means you want to say that we cannot use if condition in Select Query as asked in Question?

Comment: @Murtaza: I'm not sure I follow your question. I meant to imply that what OP's pseudocode would translate to in T-SQL is the above piece of code. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: no i am not asking you anything related to that, but a simple select query. as i am interested in answer

Comment: @Murtaza: I don't understand what you're saying at all. My answer seems to have answered OP's question. If you have a question of your own, I suggest you create a question where you explain your specific problem, so that anyone may answer it in an appropriate manner. Consider using examples, as I am somewhat lost by your description.

Comment: Thats fine i will post my question with example. Thanks